# Pyomo - Fix the value of a variable only in some constraints but not all

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

In pyomo, is it possible to fix the value of a variable only in some constraints.
Here is an example:

```
def constraint_1(m): # In constraint_1 the value of var is fixed to 1 only if someCondition holds true
    if someCondition:
        model.var.fix(1) # Fix var to value 1 only in constraint_1 if someCondition holds true
    return m.var <= 2
model.constraint_1 = Constraint(model.set, rule = constraint_1)
    
def constraint_2(m): # In constraint_2 the value of var is never fixed
    return m.var => 2
model.constraint_2 = Constraint(model.set, rule = constraint_2)
```

I wonder if this would work or if the value of var would also be fixed in constraint_2 if someCondition holds true.

Comment: No. That is not possible. (Not in Pyomo or in any other tool). Just take `var` out of that constraint and replace it with a number.

Comment: If you fix the `var`, it will be fixed anywhere. You can use two different `vars` and constraint them to be equal to a fixed value if a condition is met. Remember that using an `if` statement the condition should not involve any `var` but `params`

Comment: Can you create a variable that is constrained by (or constrains) the variable in question and use that new variable in the desired constraints?